# Spring Data: How to select from a table as you would poll from a queue

Tags: spring, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with entries which need to be processed by some user. 
I do not want multiple users to process the same row and also every 
row only needs to get processed once.

My first idea was to do something like this:

```
@Named
class OrderService @Inject constructor(
        private val repository: OrderRepository
) {
    private val queue: Queue<Order> = LinkedList()

    fun getNextOrder(): Order? {
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            var orders: List<Order> = repository.findTop1000()

            orders.forEach {
                queue.offer(it)
            }
        }

        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            return queue.poll()
        }

        return null
    }
}
```

If the queue is empty select the next 1000 entries in the db and load it into the queue. 
If after that the queue is not empty return the next element from the queue, return null otherwise.

This would work for sure... but I keep thinking that there must be a much better way of doing this.

Imagine I would change this endpoint to return multiple `Order`'s and make it pageable. With 
such a queueing I would have to do additional things to make sure that I always return the 
expected page size. So if the queue only contains 5 elements, but the page size is 10 I would 
have to check if there are more elements in the db and fill the queue before it is empty.

It would be great if there would be a mechanism to "lock" a row so that it cannot get selected 
from the table as long as it is being processed.

This could again be solved very easily by adding something like a `status` column and select only rows `where status != processing` but then the question would be: What if I request a row, set the `status` to `processing` and after that never process it (maybe because I finished working or closed the browser or whatever before saving it). I would have `status = processing` forever.

Are there already good solutions for such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something as follows:

1. Use a column named in_process_by and write the id of user who is processing it. Using id of the user would help you debug if there is some problem in production.
2. Use a column named is_processed to store the status of processing
3. Use a column named processing_started to store the time when processing was started
4. Each user would query the table where in_process_by is null and in_process is false and (now() - processing_started) < [timeout] seconds, and get n records to process.
5. Set in_process_by the id of user, is_processed to false and processing_started to now()
6. After user has processed the record, he needs to update the record and set is_processed to true.
7. Using [@Schedule](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks), update table after [timeout] seconds. You need to update those records where in_process_by is not null, is_processed is false and (now() - processing_started) > [timeout] seconds. You need to update in_process_by to null, is_processed to false and processing_started to '1970-01-01'
8. Use conditional update to only allow user to update the record that has in_process_by the id of this user